# SearchView on ActionBar: How to perform SQLite search on a custom Listview with custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have a custom `ListView` with multiple `EditText`s and I would like to make the searching function work with only one of the `EditText`s.

I was able to implement the `SearchView` on the `ActionBar` so far, but I have no idea how to search within my SQLite database using the onQueryTextChange/Submit methods.

I looked ALL over the youtube and google and could not find absolutely nothing explicitly helpful on working with a custom listview. I was able to find some nice examples on working with a simple listview without SQLite data, but I am not sure how to adapt those to my case... I really need help, please!!

If you need *any* other info, please feel free to ask and I will post right away. Thank you very much!

**CODE**

*View of my customAdapter*

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    Cliente cliente = lista.get(position);

    if(view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_listar_cliente, null);
    }

    TextView txtNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cliente_nome);
    txtNome.setText(cliente.getNome());

    TextView txtSobrenome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cliente_sobrenome);
    txtSobrenome.setText(cliente.getSobrenome());

    //
    Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cliente_opcoes);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("working", "k");
            //Mensagem.Msg(ListarCliente, "oi",1000);
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

Comment: Use cursor adapter see this [Tutorial](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html)

Comment: Harry, please post it as an answer so I can select you as the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use ArrayAdapter, it provides easy method getFilter() which will filter data out in the list according to search text.
But to use same functionality with database you need to use **CursorAdapter** : [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.htm)

Which provides method [setFilterQueryProvider(filterQueryProvider)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#setFilterQueryProvider(android.widget.FilterQueryProvider))
Where you need to pass the text and according query in database class.
See below tutorial which provides exact implementation of this:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your question if you are trying to provide the list of suggestions that drop down when user is typing, or if you want to just handle the search by running your query and displaying results in your UI.

In either case you need to write a content provider. You should already be familiar with content providers if you are using SQLite, but if not, you should probably [Start Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

If you are trying to populate the list of suggestions, it's fairly easy task to define your content provider by just extending the SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider. There is alot of information on this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html)