# Android - Actionbar with Search Filter and setting icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I am trying to implement my Action Bar by using an Action Bar.
I have two Action Buttons, one of which is a Search Button and the second one is for the Settings.

I have implemented a setting Button, but I can't implement a Search View.

How can I implement that?
Do you have any idea on how I can achieve that?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: Please reffer this link : http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/04/android-action-bar-search-inside.html

Comment: manDroid Thank you reply but i am trying to search view open not on click on search image

Comment: Tim i have already but i cant understand please explain  i m trying to implement same  action bar

Comment: @Sambhaji take a look on my post maybe it will be helpful for you If you have any question just ask :)

Comment: see my [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597045/searchview-on-actionbar-how-to-perform-sqlite-search-on-a-custom-listview-with/29619993#29619993) in similar question, vote up if it is helpful.

Comment: i want to this http://developer.android.com/images/search/search-ui.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the first step you have to prepare `search_menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>

  ... your others menu items
</menu>
```

In the next step you have to use this menu in your `Fragment` or `Activity` and set `OnQueryTextListener` for your `SearchView` as is shown in the code below:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

    final SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to use menu in fragment remember about `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` method.

If you want to customise your `SearchView` you have to create your own style for this as is shown in the code below:

```
<style name="CustomAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/CustomSearchViewStyle
    </item>
</style>
<style name="CustomSearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <!-- Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText) -->
    <item name="queryBackground">...</item>
    <!-- Background for the actions section (e.g. voice, submit) -->
    <item name="submitBackground">...</item>
    <!-- Close button icon -->
    <item name="closeIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Search button icon -->
    <item name="searchIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Go/commit button icon -->
    <item name="goIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Voice search button icon -->
    <item name="voiceIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Commit icon shown in the query suggestion row -->
    <item name="commitIcon">...</item>
    <!-- Layout for query suggestion rows -->
    <item name="suggestionRowLayout">...</item>
</style>
```

**EXAMPLE** To get old style of `EditText` in `SearchView`

```
<style name="CustomAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/CustomSearchViewStyle
    </item>
</style>
<style name="CustomSearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="queryBackground">@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal</item>
</style>
```

Remember to set this style in AndroidManifest for your Activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/CustomAppTheme"
```