# How to add a searchView that will retrieve data already entered on SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

*I would like to know what I need to add to this app so that I can view data entered from the database in the searchview.I have already created an example where there is a search facility but it has hardcoded strings,in this case I want the user to see data that they have entered in the database.Could please tell me what is required for this to work?Thank you*

*This my Main Class*

package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static Button button_change;
    DatabaseClass myDb;
    EditText editText_name,editText_Quantity,editText_Category,editTextId,editText_Number;
    Button button_add;
    Button btnviewAll;
    Button btnviewUpdate;
    Button btnDelete;
    ListView lv;
    SearchView sv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        myDb = new DatabaseClass(this);

        editText_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        editText_Quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Quantity);
        editText_Category = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Category);
        editText_Number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Number);
        editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_id);
        button_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        btnviewAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view_all);
        btnviewUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_update);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);


        AddData();
        viewAll();
        updateData();
        DeleteData();
        // OnClickButtonListener();


    }





    public void DeleteData(){
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Integer deletedRows = myDb.DeleteData(editTextId.getText().toString());
                        if(deletedRows > 0)
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Data is Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Data is not Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }



                }

        );
    }
    public void updateData(){
        btnviewUpdate.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        boolean isUpdate = myDb.updateData(editTextId.getText().toString(), editText_name.getText().toString(),editText_Quantity.getText().toString(),
                                editText_Category.getText().toString(),editText_Number.getText().toString());
                        if ( isUpdate == true)
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Data is Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Data is not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }}
        );

    }
    public void AddData() {
        button_add.setOnClickListener(

                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (editText_name.getText().toString().length() == 0)

                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product Name cannot be Blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            editText_name.setError("Product Name cannot be Blank");
                            return;
                        }
                            else if(editText_Quantity.getText().toString().length() == 0){

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Quantity cannot be Blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            editText_Quantity.setError("Quantity cannot be Blank");
                            return;

                        }

                        else if(editText_Category.getText().toString().length() == 0) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID cannot be Blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            editText_Category.setError("ID cannot be Blank");
                            return;
                        }

                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Validated Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editText_name.getText().toString(),
                                editText_Quantity.getText().toString(),
                                editText_Category.getText().toString(),editText_Number.getText().toString());
                        if (isInserted = true)
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Data is Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Data is not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                        }
                    }

        );





    }

    public void viewAll(){
        btnviewAll.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
                        if(res.getCount()==0){
                            //show message
                            showMessage("Error","Nothing found");
                            return;
                        }
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        while(res.moveToNext()){
                            buffer.append("Id:"+res.getString(0)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Name:"+res.getString(1)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Quantity:"+res.getString(2)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Food Category:"+res.getString(3)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("Importance of Product:"+res.getString(4)+"\n");
                        }
                        //show all data
                        showMessage("Data",buffer.toString());
                    }
                }

        );
    }
    public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.show();

    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.action_settings : startActivity (new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
break;
                case R.id.catalogue :startActivity (new Intent(this, ScrollActivity.class));
                    break;

                case R.id.list :startActivity (new Intent(this, Product_List.class));
                    break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }}
}
```

*And this my Db Class*

```
public class DatabaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_Name = "Product.db2";
    public static final String Table_Name = "product_table2";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "Name";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Quantity";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Category";
    public static final String COL_5 = "Importance";
    public DatabaseClass(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_Name, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + Table_Name + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,Quantity TEXT,Category INTEGER,Importance TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exists" + Table_Name);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String quantity, String category,String importance) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, category);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, importance);

        long result = db.insert(Table_Name, null, contentValues);

            if (result == -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + Table_Name, null);
        return res;
    }

    public boolean updateData(String id,String name,String quantity,String category,String importance ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, category);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, importance);
        db.update(Table_Name,contentValues,"id =?",new String[]{id});
                return true;
    }

    public Integer DeleteData (String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(Table_Name,"ID = ?",new String[]{id});
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SearchView on ActionBar: How to perform SQLite search on a custom Listview with custom adapter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597045/searchview-on-actionbar-how-to-perform-sqlite-search-on-a-custom-listview-with)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate ,I would like someone to explain it to me ,as I'm not very good with Android programming .

Comment: Hmm, sorry, then. I did find some YouTube videos and official Android Documentation on using Search View and Sqlite

Comment: There are no videos on Youtube where I see both SQLite and searchview being implemented together ,where the user searches the data that they entered through a searchView.If you have found something like this please send me the link,that  would be a big help,thank you.

Comment: Here's just one example I found with a search for "android sqlite searchview"  http://instinctcoder.com/android-studio-sqlite-search-searchview-actionbar/